# Python- Unable to retrieve complete text data for 1 more pages

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie in Python Programming and I am facing following issue:
Objective: I need to scrap Freelancers website and store the list of theusers along with their attributes (score, ratings,reviews,details, rate,etc) 
into a file. I have following codes but I am not able to get all the users.

Also, sometimes I run the program, the output changes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = 1
fileWriter =open('freelancers.txt','w')
url = 'https://www.freelancer.com/freelancers/skills/all/'+str(pages)+'/'
r = requests.get(url)

#gets the html contents and stores them into soup object

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.findAll("a")

#Finds the freelancer-details nodes and stores the html content into c_data

c_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"freelancer-details"})
for item in c_data:
    print item.text 
    fileWriter.write('Freelancers Details:'+item.text+'\t')
#Writes the result into text file
```

I need to get the user details under specific users. But so far, the output looks dispersed.

Sample Output:
   Freelancers Details:

```
thetechie13
507 Reviews




$20 USD/hr

Top Skills:

       Website Design, 


       HTML, 


       PHP, 


       eCommerce, 


       Volusion

Dear Customer - We are a team of 75 Most Creative People and proud to be
Preferred Freelancer on  Freelancer.com. We offer wide range of web
solutions and IT services that are bespoke in nature, can best fit our
clients' business needs and provide them cost benefits.
```

Comment: Give a sample of the output.

Comment: `he output looks dispersed` How does this differ from what you expect? What is you **exact** problem? You must be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I have provided sample output for one user, I need these details mapped together. This is just for one user where as I need these details for all the users on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each individual text component on its own (each assigned a different name), I would advise you to parse the text from from the HTML separately. However if you want it all grouped together you could join the strings:

```
print ' '.join(item.text.split())
```

This will place a single space between each word.